# Google Apps Script: Trouble Passing URL Params from doGet() to doPost()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I'm having trouble getting a variable passed from `doGet()` into `doPost()`. When the variable `sheetName` is defined globally without any logic to define it, it works fine, but when I use `doGet()` to define it using a URL parameter, it won't load the form submission data into my Google Sheet. Basically I'm trying to define the sheet name so I can reuse the code for separate tabs inside the same sheet. Changing `sheetName` to 'Sheet2' works fine and passes the data into that sheet (assuming the headers are setup properly). I feel like it might be a load order where `doGet()` is getting called after `doPost()` or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The base of the code I'm using was taken from here: https://forum.webflow.com/t/how-to-submit-html-form-directly-to-google-sheets/71432

my `scriptURL` is something like this: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/KEY/exec?formUsed=Sheet1`

My modified `Code.gs` code is below:

```
var sheetName;

function doGet(request){
  sheetName = request.parameter.formUsed;
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(sheetName);
}

//var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function setup() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', doc.getId())
}

function doPost(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.waitLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      'result': 'success',
      'row': nextRow
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  } catch (e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      'result': 'error',
      'error': e
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a GET request to your script, it will set the value of `sheetName`, and then return that to the user. After returning, the script finishes execution and `sheetName` is no longer defined.

Then, when you receive the POST request *another*, separate instance of the script is executed, so `sheetName` is undefined.

The variables only hold their values for the single execution instance. To retain values across executions, you should save to [`Properties`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties).

```
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function doGet(request){
  scriptProp.setProperty('sheetName', request.parameter.formUsed);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(sheetName);
}

function setup() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', doc.getId())
}

function doPost(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.waitLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(scriptProp.getProperty('sheetName'))
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      'result': 'success',
      'row': nextRow
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  } catch (e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      'result': 'error',
      'error': e
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Diego! I tried setting the `Property` at one point, but I must have been doing it wrong. Thank you so much for your quick response!

For anyone that comes along and finds this later, you'll need to trigger a `GET` and then a `POST` on the front-end to push the data to the Google Sheet.